# Reference for the existence of bicolimits in groupoids and categories?

Tags: limits-and-colimits, groupoids, 2-categories

I am looking for a reference of these, I would say, very well known facts. (strangely though finding a reference was bit trick for me).

1. Let $C$ be a category and $F:C\rightarrow Cat$ a 2-functor in the 2-category of categories. Then the bicolimit of $F$ exists.
2. Let $C$ be a category and $F:C\rightarrow Grpd$ a 2-functor in the 2-category of groupoids. Then the bicolimit of $F$ exists.

Has anyone got a clear reference for this?

Also, as sort of a bonus question :), if $F$ took values in groupoids, then it should not matter where we take the bicolimits, in categories or groupoids. Anyone got a reference for that fact as well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: bump. (sorry but I kinda need the references :) ).